# Describing sequences that satisfy $\forall \delta>0 : \forall N \in \mathbb{N} : \exists n>N, |b_n-L|<\delta$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

i have been thinking about what would happen if i changed some of the quantifiers in the definition of convergence of a sequence.

i am wondering what property (or properties) (general form/description) sequences satisfying

$\forall \delta>0 : \forall N \in \mathbb{N} : \exists n>N, |b_n-L|<\delta$

have, where $b_n$ is the $n^{th}$term of the sequence and $L$ is the limit of the sequence as $n$ tends to infinity.

I am not sure how to approach this and would appreciate some help.

Comment: Convergent sequences would satisfy the condition. But there are sequences satisfying the condition that do not converge. A sequence that oscillates to a point and away from it infinitely often, for example. A simple example is $(-1)^n$. For this sequence, the condition is satisfied for both $L=1$ and $-1$.

Comment: Nothing special other than convergence.

Answer (score 4):

Your condition implies (and is equivalent to) the sequence having a subsequence convergent to $L.$ For example, if your sequence is that of the rationals in some order, you will get that this property will be satisfied for any $L.$

Comment: thank you for your answer. how would we go about proving this equivalence?

Answer (score 2):

In English, this property is "an infinite subsequence of $(b_n)$ converges to $L$".

If an infinite subsequence $(b_{m_i})$ converges to $L$, the definition of convergence means for any $\delta>0$ there is some $M$ such that $i>M$ implies $|b_{m_i} - L| < \delta$, so for any $N$ we can take $K = \max(M, N) + 1$ and $n=m_K>N$ identifies an element $b_n$ satisfying $|b_n - L| < \delta$. Your property is also satisfied.

If $(b_n)$ satisfies your property, then for any $\gamma > 0$ we can take $N=1$ and $\delta=1$ to find $m_0$ with $|b_{m_0}| < 1$; then recursively take $N=m_n$ and $\delta=2^{-n}$ to find $m_{n+1}$ with $|b_{m_{n+1}} - L| < 2^{-n}$. Then $(b_{m_i})$ is an infinite subsequence which converges to $L$.

Answer (score 0):

If a sequence $(b_n)_n$ satisfies, for $L \in \mathbb R$ (let's work with $\mathbb R$ for the sake of simplicity),
$$\forall \delta>0 : \forall N \in \mathbb{N} : \exists n>N, |b_n-L|<\delta$$
then $(b_n)_n$ admits a subsequence converging toward $L$. Indeed, define $(b_{n_k})_k$ the following way:
$$n_k = \min \{s > n_{k-1}~|~|b_s- L| < 1/k\}.$$
You may check that $(b_{n_k})_k$ converges towards $L$.